# negative dimensions are not allowed in GIS

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, gis

I define coordinates for cities, it worked for one city, but not for others

```
almaty = df.loc[(df['latitude']>= 43.117971)&(df['latitude'] <= 51.21465 )& (df['longitude']>= 76.3)&(df['longitude']<= 77.017043)]
astana = df.loc[(df['latitude']>=43.67 )&(df['latitude'] <= 49.33  )& (df['longitude']>=71.4 )&(df['longitude']<=71.7 )]
shymkent = df.loc[(df['latitude']>= 43.3006564195014)&(df['latitude'] <=43.393584  )& (df['longitude']>=69.521168 )&(df['longitude']<=69.796007 )]
karaganda = df.loc[(df['latitude']>= 49.180286)&(df['latitude'] <=49.975897 )& (df['longitude']>=73.007664 )&(df['longitude']<=73.216594 )]
aktobe = df.loc[(df['latitude']>=43.157950342428 )&(df['latitude'] <= 43.202757)& (df['longitude']>= 57.037496)&(df['longitude']<= 57.309703)]
aktay = df.loc[(df['latitude']>= 41.091843)&(df['latitude'] <=42.321688)& (df['longitude']>= 51.0684404142448)&(df['longitude']<= 51.242566)]
atyray = df.loc[(df['latitude']>=42.373844 )&(df['latitude'] <=42.878625)& (df['longitude']>= 51.829899)&(df['longitude']<= 51.976558)]
taraz = df.loc[(df['latitude']>=43.638035)&(df['latitude'] <= 43.860407)& (df['longitude']>=71.289942 )&(df['longitude']<=71.383097 )]
oral = df.loc[(df['latitude']>=53.218562)&(df['latitude'] <=53.91340984)& (df['longitude']>= 51.268246)&(df['longitude']<= 51.5)]
kostanay = df.loc[(df['latitude']>=43.226135)&(df['latitude'] <=43.231757)& (df['longitude']>= 63.539098)&(df['longitude']<= 63.682181)]
ust_kam = df.loc[(df['latitude']>= 53.218562)&(df['latitude'] <= 53.91340984)& (df['longitude']>=82.548347 )&(df['longitude']<=82.775019 )]
turkestan = df.loc[(df['latitude']>=43.253377)&(df['latitude'] <=43.26444)& (df['longitude']>=68.193404 )&(df['longitude']<=68.340979 )]
kzyl_orda = df.loc[(df['latitude']>=43.235554 )&(df['latitude'] <=43.241596)& (df['longitude']>= 65.357)&(df['longitude']<=65.5872052968506 )]
semei = df.loc[(df['latitude']>=52.305741)&(df['latitude'] <= 52.910023 )& (df['longitude']>= 80.421254)&(df['longitude']<=81.068463)]
```

Almaty is working, but others don't.

```
fig = ff.create_hexbin_mapbox(
data_frame=almaty, lat=almaty.latitude, lon=almaty.longitude,
nx_hexagon=60, opacity=0.5, labels={"color": "Point Count"},
min_count=5, color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
show_original_data=True,zoom=10,
original_data_marker=dict(size=4, opacity=0.6, color="deeppink",
                         )
```

)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.show()

Working

```
fig = ff.create_hexbin_mapbox(
data_frame=astana, lat=astana.latitude, lon=astana.longitude,
nx_hexagon=10, opacity=0.5, labels={"color": "Point Count"},
min_count=5, color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
show_original_data=True,zoom=10,
original_data_marker=dict(size=4, opacity=0.6, color="deeppink",
                         )
```

)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.show()

Not working

Comment: Did you check the content of `astana`? and what difference it has with "almaty"?

Comment: Yes, just another coordinates